# TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeRole' of undefined When trying to reference a user from a split message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my discord bot to remove a role from a user, but I am having trouble. When I try to run the command it gives the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeRole' of undefined, and I don't know how to fix it, as verify[1] is a user.
Code:

```js
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!accept')) {
    let verify = msg.content.split(", ");

    let person = verify[1]; //Person is an @ like @Llama's Tester#7151

    person.member.removeRole('744427032783355965');
    person.send(accept);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** as mentioned by @Lioness100

> You can use message.mentions.users.first() – Lioness100 1 hour ago

I am not sure if your code is correct.

1. Firstly, you are splitting message (string): `let verify = msg.content.split(", ");`
2. After that you are accessing 2nd item in the array of strings:
   `let person = verify[1];`
3. Now you are accessing `member` on string: `person.member.removeRole('744427032783355965');`

definitely you are going to get this error as `string` does not have `member` property.

Comment: Okay, is there a way I can make the string into a member object?

Comment: May be I am not sure what your data looks like, but even in that case, if you parse string to JSON object there is no guarantee it will have `removeRole` method.

Comment: The message that is split looks like this: https://imgur.com/HXFTNX9

Comment: That is string and you can only perform string related operations on it.

Comment: I know there's a way to do this, since Dyno uses it in moderation, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can use [`message.mentions.users.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)

Comment: Just found that on a website, thanks anyways. Do I mark this answer as the correct one or do you make an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?